# Duplicate record found in List<T> with the same index & HashCode

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL, and my list is List<PriceData>, and I am kind sure I have check the existence before add the PriceData item into the list, and even it's duplicated, it should have the different index in the list, sample code as below

```
lock(marketRaw)
{
    if(marketRaw.IndexOf(price.Symbol) < 0)
    marketRaw.Add(price);
}

...

int myidx = 0;
foreach (PriceData item in marketRaw)
{
    myidx++;
    if (item.Symbol == "KLIV5")
        Console.WriteLine("KLIV5 @ " + myidx.ToString() + " ==> " + item.GetHashCode().ToString();
}
```

Here marketRaw is List<PriceData>, and the result is below

```
KLIV5 @ 606 ==> 40835417
KLIV5 @ 606 ==> 40835417
```

What happen?

Comment: What type is `item`? What other fields does it have? Could there actually be two identical items in your `marketRaw` data. If you could show your code that adds items to the list we could check whether that was correct.

Comment: Can it be, that you just run your loop twice?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't reproduce nor analyze this from the code shown. Also, if your output prints the **same index twice (606)**, chances are the problem lies somewhere else, for example in your loop code... The code you show only loops once, so cannot give the output shown.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary with the `Symbol` as the key if you don't want to allow duplicates?

Comment: `List<T>` makes no guarantees concerning uniqueness. You've put the same thing into it, twice.

Comment: What you describe is simply impossible from the code you have posted (repeat in the printed value of myidx) without a major bug in the compiler, which is frankly highly unlikely. Please follow @CodeCaster's advice.

Comment: @spender that would not explain why the _index_ is the same for the two outputs.

Comment: @ChrisF i have edit my post

Comment: @Leo.W That is not enough to fully diagnose.  Could you be calling the code that calls `foreach` twice?

Comment: @DStanley OK, i'll update again my project to let myidx to be the Static Global variable and update the result again

Comment: @Leo.W: You write "the result is below", and there are only two lines in the result. You are omitting the rest of the result, I'm guessing `marketRow` has more than two items? Where exactly does the repeating line occur?

Comment: @Leo.W Making `myidx` static could make the problem _worse_.  If another thread comes along and updates it you could have _very_ strange behavior.

Comment: @DStanley Considering multi threading, i will make use of the Interlock

Comment: @Leo.W How do you expect making it static (even _with_ locking) to help? Don't _guess_ at what the problem is - run it in the debugger ,see where it gets called and look at the stack trace.  I suspect something (perhaps unintentionally) is calling the function twice.  I can;t see how you could get the results you indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of hard to understand your question, but I think that what you are expecting is that a `List<T>` will ensure uniqueness by Equals and Hashcode. It will not- you should use a `HashSet<T>` for that purpose.